# Time Series data visualization

Tags: time-series, visualization, matplotlib, plotly

When I visualize data using matplotlib it displays very well, but when using Plotly, the data display very bad.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the plot type on Plotly to line:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x="Date", y="Close", title='COMERCIAL INTERNATIONAL BANK')
fig.show()
```

Comment: I try it, the same result.Worried about the data being problematic and needed preprocessing

Comment: I have had the same problem that you have in plotly but in matplotlib. In your place I would try, sorting my dataframe by date and then plot in plotly

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing `X` because it's an index.